# Build in jenkins depending on git branch

Tags: cmd, msbuild

## Good day everyone. I am trying to solve a problem with a build depending on the git branch.

Expected Result: After "if = master" the master folder should be created. If it is "if! = Master" then various.
I suspect that the condition does not work at all, because the folder is always created.

### I tried like this:

```
SET branch=%GIT_BRANCH:*/=%
if ($ branch -eq "test") {
    Write-Output "Branch test"
}
if ($ branch = "master") {
   MD "C: \ Jenkins \ workspace \ Api \ Api_DEV \ API_Build_Master_Test \ Master"
}
else {
   MD "C: \ Jenkins \ workspace \ Api \ Api_DEV \ API_Build_Master_Test \ Various"
}
```

But this method does not work at all, it gives the following error
C: \ Jenkins \ workspace \ Api \ Api_DEV \ API_Build_Master_Test> SET branch = test-eq was unexpected at this time.
I make steps for windows in jenkins, that is, I execute under cmd

Comment: Why are there so many SPACE characters? What is the intended result of `SET branch =% GIT_BRANCH: * / =%`? It looks like it would be intended to replace `* / ` with nothing. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: Yes, there are too many gaps.
SET branch =% GIT_BRANCH: * / =%
And about this, is there any value to be substituted?
I'm just new to this beginner.
In general, as I understand it, the value of the remote branch SET branch =% GIT_BRANCH should be substituted into this variable: * / =%

Comment: Do an `ECHO %GIT_BRANCH%` to see what the value is before this script starts. Also, there should probably not be SPACE characters around the path separator `\` character. Think of that as something that `DIR` would use.

Comment: I tried ECHO% GIT_BRANCH%.
Produced the result "ECHO origin / test"
This means the parameter is correctly passed to the variable. So the problem is with the code that goes further

Comment: @lit. Good day, your function works just fine. I wanted to ask you if it is possible to make it so that if == master, the msbuild project is going to the Master folder, and if not master, then it is going to Various

Comment: what causes msbuild project to choose the directory? Is it a variable?

Comment: @lit. 
Generally. As I understand it, I need to specify the / p: OutDir parameter in the msbuild step of jenkins.
But in my case it does not work, it throws an error of MongoDB dependencies (they are not pulled up)
Although it works for other stackoverflow users.

Comment: @lit. Good day. I use the following parameters in the msbuild jenkins step:
/ p: OutDir =% BUILD_ROOT% \ Various / p: AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings = false / p: Build = True / t: Clean, Rebuild.
On Friday, it just happened to copy the project files to the desired folder, but now I realized that this is not working correctly, it creates folders after the main one and copies them to them. And you need him to create copied files to the project along this path C: \ Jenkins \ workpsace \ Api \ Api_DEV \ API \ Build \ Master - Master or Various (depending on the branch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the question seems to be a mix of cmd and PowerShell, both with invalid syntax for either language. The first line appears to remove everything before the first SOLIDUS (forward slash) character in the GIT_BRANCH variable.

What happens with this?

```
SET "branch=%GIT_BRANCH:*/ =%"
if "%branch%" == "test" (ECHO Branch test)

if ("%branch%" == "master") (
    MKDIR "C:\Jenkins\workspace\Api\Api_DEV\API_Build_Master_Test\Master"
) else (
    MKDIR "C:\Jenkins\workspace\Api\Api_DEV\API_Build_Master_Test\Various"
)
```

**UPDATE:**

```
SET "branch=%GIT_BRANCH:*/ =%"
if "%branch%" == "test" (ECHO Branch test)

ECHO branch is set to ===%branch%===

SET "BUILD_ROOT=C:\Jenkins\workspace\Api\Api_DEV\API_Build_Master_Test"

if ("%branch%" == "master") (
    IF NOT EXIST "%BUILD_ROOT%\Master" (MKDIR "%BUILD_ROOT%\Master")
) else (
    IF NOT EXIST "%BUILD_ROOT%\Various" (MKDIR "%BUILD_ROOT%\Various")
)
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, I found part of this code on the site with documentation for using if in powershell.
But as the forums on using in cmd have shown, it seems that there is a dumb similar structure.
And about the first line, this is a built-in parameter in jenkins, the parameter must be sent to it via a webhook from github.
Nothing happens with this code, the assembly immediately crashes.

Comment: I checked your code, it works correctly with if == test, a Various folder is created, but with if == master, for some reason, a Various folder is created, that is, this part is most likely skipped:
 MKDIR "C: \ Jenkins \ workspace \ Api \ Api_DEV \ API_Build_Master_Test \ Master"

Comment: Now everything works, bracket ")" after:
if "% branch%" == "master")
Now it works in 2 cases.
Thank you very much for your help. I wish you success and prosperity

Comment: I made changes on the first line assuming that there is a SPACE character after  `\ ` and before `test` in the variable. Also used a variable for the build root directory. If this is the best answer you have received, please select the check mark to indicate that to others who might have a similar issue. That is how SO works.

Comment: I checked your last option, this option does not create the Master folder, only Various. I tried removing the parentheses, but it didn't help

Comment: @DanilaMylnikov, please use the ECHO added in the last code to see what the actual value is? The `===` will show if there are SPACE or other whitespace characters preceding or after the %branch% string.